# How to call an item only for the first time of running

Tags: java, android, visibility

I would like to show a "png" image to the user,  but only for the first time the app runs, so for subsequent runs it will not appear.

I normally do it like this:

```
helpimg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Then, by using the `OnTouchlistener` function I can make it disappear, but this method would have to be used every time the user runs my app.
I need to do it just for the first time because it's just an introductory help image which gives the user the instructions on how to use the app.
So how can I code this ??

Comment: Use a file or SharedPreferences to remember whether you've already shown it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using the [SharedPreferece](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html). For example:

```
//Check if the image has been shown
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean first = sharedPref.getBoolean("first", true);
if(first){
    helpimg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //Set the preference to false
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("first", false);
    editor.commit();
}else{
    helpimg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: So i will make my image invisible then after if(first) i write :helpimg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); ,,,,, so that will solve my problem ??!?